# Developing c# library that is called from VBA

Tags: c#, vba, office-interop

I create a function in VBA like so:

```vb
Sub TPS_Test()

    Dim classLib As Object
    ' remember you must type the set... line in its entirity when incrimenting to new version.  Something about their compiling
    
    Set classLib = New RoadTrip_v14_1_9.TripDoc
    classLib.TPS_Test Excel.ActiveWorkbook, False
    
End Sub
```

And adding the C# library from VBA - tools - reference (Compile the library as a type library first).

That works, and I can attach the library to Excel.exe process and debug that way.

However, for every code change I need to recompile, reimport into VBA, and run again.

My process:

1. Increment the name of the project (Myproject_V1).
2. Compile
3. Remove reference to old library in VBA
4. Add reference to new library.
5. Change class names in VBA (set classLib = new Myproject_v1)
6. Attach C# library to excel process.
7. Rerun the VBA module.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you proceed in that way, modifying the library name, you do not have any other choice, i am afraid. But keeping the name unchanged and keep track of the application versions in a different way, theoretically, there is no need of such a complicated process, if the referenced library can be all the time found on the same path.

Comment: @FaneDuru you would still have to go through this process of attaching the newly compiled library to the VBA project right?

Comment: I think, not. Theoretically, the system cannot know the content of the referenced library, if it keeps the same name and exists in the same path. Did you try this way? I would try referencing it from the solution 'Bin' folder. I must confess that I did not do something similar because I did not need something like this. I am talking strictly theoretically...

Comment: You can recompile the library without having to re add each time in VBA if you do not change the name.  I do this all the time.  Judging by your comments you haven't yet discovered the benefits of unit testing.  Lookup MSTest for C#.  Its fairly simple to use.  Basically you should have a set of tests in a seperate C# class in a second project in your solution that exercise the various methods your class provides so that when you get to VBA you know that the class works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to responders.  The best way to do this is to generate unit tests in C# that will load the excel file then run C# code against it, in visual studio.

The second thing as they pointed out, you can reuse the same file name, just close excel, compile, open excel.

Answer (score 0):

3 years later, this is somewhat popular.  This is what I ended up doing eventually.  Created an excel DNA plugin, which is the C# project.  The plugin just needs to be copied to a user-specified directory and the user needs to enable the plug-in.

THis allows you to modify the code all you want, and you just need to pack the DLL into the addin packaging (Excel DNA does this), and simply copy to the right directory.  No more registering COM and messing with VBA.